# Angular 5 Oauth2.0 basic auth POST request returns 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I wanted to get access token using post request.

can anybody help me why this happens?

```
let _httpParams = new HttpParams()
.set("username","username")
.set("password","password")
.set("grant_type","password")

let _httpHeader = new HttpHeaders();
_httpHeader = _httpHeader.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
_httpHeader = _httpHeader.append("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa("username:password"));

return this._http.post(API_URL+'/oauth/token',{headers: _httpHeader,params: _httpParams})
```

I always got this result

[image]

Comment: Did you try calling this post request using postman or any other rest client?

Comment: yes in postman it is working.

Comment: it's working with the same process. I tried to do it with angular and it gives me this error

Comment: Can you add the complete code for your http request

Comment: What does `btoa` do? Surely your `Authorization` header should contain a base64 encoded string of your client id and secret rather than the user id and password?

Comment: its a angular built in function for encoding base64

Comment: Ok, so are you encoding the client credentials or the user credentials? Your example implies user. It should be client.